# How to create custom content editor web part in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

How to create custom content editor web part in classic experience of share point online ?

Comment: Why do you not use the out of the box content editor web part? Why the need for a custom web part? And maybe you need to state your question in more than one sentence. As a new user, please take the [tour] and then learn [ask]

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Online classic experience provide OOTB Content Editor Web Part, you could directly use it to embed custom CSS/JavaScript code:

[Content Editor Web Part](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/content-editor-web-part-c1350ff6-934c-4c2e-8e53-1ec3b548a0dc)